# Spring returning custom response rest repository call

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I've got a rest respository resource for an entity, and i'm actually performing some rest calls to it.

I've successfully done a DELETE rest call using jquery and te browser get a 204 HTTP response.

By googling this code, i found out that it's actually a success code answer which has no content.

I wonder if it's possible to configure the rest api in the backend so that it returns a json representation of the operation success... something like:

```
{
    operationType: "deletion",
    entity: "entityName,
    message: "succesfully deleted the entity identified by 35"
}
```

I'm aware that it has something to do with creating a pojo class and using ResponseEntity but don't know how to configure it.

Comment: You can create an Entity with those fields and then return it as a RespnseEntity<CustomMessage> after successful deletion from the rest API.

Comment: @dassum is right. I would like to add spring documentation link for custom handler for spring data rest. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers